# Struts 2 Download a pdf or word doc file stored into MySql Database as Blob Type

Tags: mysql, struts2, pdf-generation, blob

I have saved a pdf and word doc files into MySql database as Blob type, and i want to convert it into origin file and download it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I've seen thos question, but it isn't same with mine. Cause i've saved the into Database as Blob Type

Comment: @Roman C. this is not exact duplicate of that question, Here pdf is stored entirely in the database not just location. Please remove the duplicate mark.